# Attempt to double size of SDL_Surface fails horribly

Tags: c, resize, sdl, interpolation

source is always 320x240, dest is always 640x480.

```
void DoDoubleScaling(SDL_Surface* dest, SDL_Surface* source)
{
    assert(dest->w == source->w*2);
    assert(dest->h == source->h*2);
    for (int y = 0; y < source->h; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < source->w; ++x)
        {
            SetPixel(dest, x*2, y*2, GetPixel(source, x, y));
            SetPixel(dest, x*2+1, y*2+1, GetPixel(source, x, y));
        }
    }
}
```

The output looks like this: [image] (be sure to view at full size). Essentially, every second pixel is missing. I've tried all sorts of possibilities and I can't find where I'm going wrong.

`GetPixel`and `SetPixel` simply set/recieve a surface's colour, given an X and Y [and color].

Comment: If you double both the width and height, you effectively multiply the area by 4. So for each source pixel you need to write 4 destination pixels.

Comment: Oh crap. Yes, indeed. Solved. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
        SetPixel(dest, x*2, y*2, GetPixel(source, x, y));
        SetPixel(dest, x*2, y*2+1, GetPixel(source, x, y));
        SetPixel(dest, x*2+1, y*2, GetPixel(source, x, y));
        SetPixel(dest, x*2+1, y*2+1, GetPixel(source, x, y));
```

Instead of:

```
        SetPixel(dest, x*2, y*2, GetPixel(source, x, y));
        SetPixel(dest, x*2+1, y*2+1, GetPixel(source, x, y));
```

And for speed up: Store return value of GetPixel(source, x, y), so you don't need to call it 4 times per each round.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why I got it into my head that (x*2)*(y*2) needed only 2 pixels rather than 4!